# Select only rows if its value in a particular column is 'NA' in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a subset of data that contains only the rows with missing data in one of my columns.

The data:

```
data<-structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 27, 28, 29, 31, 34, 37, 38, 39, 
40, 41), QnSinV1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), QnSinV2 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), QnSinV3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), QnSize = c(0.032140423, 0.017620319, 
NA, -0.093448167, -0.051090375, 0.001188913, NA, -0.144868599, 
-0.000260992, 0.008502255, -0.00346349, 0.017208373, 0.004301855, 
0.004420431, -0.007564124, NA, 0.174388101, -0.142412328, 0.064935852, 
-0.052174354, NA, 0.005180317, 0.05728222, 0.041215822, -0.002449455, 
-0.040942923, -0.082284946, -0.173656321, 0.022723036, -0.061326436
), QnWt = c(15.8, 16.5, 11.9, 13.7, 15, 15.3, 13.7, 15.8, 16.3, 
15.9, 15.1, 14.5, 14.4, 15.7, 14.4, 13.3, 14.8, 15.1, 15.1, 14.7, 
15.8, 17.8, 16.4, 13.4, 15.1, 14.8, 14.2, 12.7, 17.9, 16.2), 
QnWtLsCL = c(NA, 0.503030303, 0.596638655, NA, 0.446666667, 
0.509803922, 0.408759124, 0.462025316, 0.552147239, 0.509433962, 
0.456953642, 0.455172414, 0.506944444, NA, 0.486111111, 0.473684211, 
0.513513514, 0.516556291, 0.582781457, 0.537414966, 0.474683544, 
0.43258427, 0.432926829, NA, 0.569536424, 0.445945946, 0.485915493, 
0.543307087, NA, 0.543209877), ClaustPer = c(NA, 1L, 2L, 
NA, 3L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, NA, 0L, 7L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, NA, 0L), QnSurvCL = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), 
ColWtCL = c(NA, 11.7, 7.3, NA, 9.1, 11.1, 9.6, 11.2, 9, 11.2, 
12, 11, 10.9, NA, 9.9, 8.6, 10.8, 10.9, 8.7, 10.8, 11.6, 
13.7, 10.8, NA, 9.3, 9.6, 9.8, 8.7, NA, 11.1), ColWtCL_6 = c(NA, 
57.1, 45, NA, 73.6, NA, NA, NA, 43.8, NA, NA, 71.1, NA, NA, 
53.7, NA, 84.4, NA, NA, NA, 56, 56.1, NA, NA, 59.4, NA, 45.7, 
NA, NA, NA), ColGrowthCL_6 = c(NA, 4.88034188, 6.164383562, 
NA, 8.087912088, NA, NA, NA, 4.866666667, NA, NA, 6.463636364, 
NA, NA, 5.424242424, NA, 7.814814815, NA, NA, NA, 4.827586207, 
4.094890511, NA, NA, 6.387096774, NA, 4.663265306, NA, NA, 
NA), QnSurvCL_6 = c(NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 0L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 
NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA), IR = c(-0.1919695, 0.0214441, NA, 0.0886954, 
0.4221713, 0.0869788, 0.2716466, 0.0289674, -0.0291414, -0.1739616, 
-0.0215773, -0.1473209, 0.0370336, 0.254584, 0.0332632, -0.0203844, 
0.1524175, -0.051451, -0.0612144, 0.1617955, 0.0354173, 0.0904954, 
0.3344705, 0.0990583, 0.1985931, 0.0419539, -0.0159598, 0.1159526, 
-0.0057495, -0.1811458), SH = c(1.2064, 1.1093, NA, 0.922, 
0.643, 0.9284, 0.7225, 0.9866, 1.0804, 1.2226, 1.0315, 1.1953, 
1.007, 0.6991, 1.0264, 1.0265, 0.8865, 1.1184, 1.094, 0.829, 
1.0142, 0.9824, 0.6793, 0.9188, 0.7853, 1.0352, 1.0648, 0.9654, 
1.0366, 1.2044), HL = c(0.3774, 0.4349, NA, 0.5091, 0.6187, 
0.5168, 0.6405, 0.4691, 0.4555, 0.3444, 0.4908, 0.3819, 0.4846, 
0.6256, 0.4638, 0.4778, 0.5219, 0.433, 0.447, 0.564, 0.4899, 
0.4612, 0.6542, 0.5162, 0.5549, 0.4928, 0.4471, 0.4959, 0.4523, 
0.3511), MLH = c(0.534090909090909, 0.5, NA, 0.40506329113924, 
0.298507462686567, 0.410958904109589, 0.293103448275862, 
0.442105263157895, 0.48, 0.554347826086957, 0.453488372093023, 
0.535353535353535, 0.443298969072165, 0.304878048780488, 
0.457446808510638, 0.455555555555556, 0.397849462365591, 
0.494252873563218, 0.48314606741573, 0.377777777777778, 0.457446808510638, 
0.445652173913043, 0.3, 0.412371134020619, 0.354838709677419, 
0.464646464646465, 0.474226804123711, 0.43010752688172, 0.46078431372549, 
0.541666666666667)), .Names = c("ID", "QnSinV1", "QnSinV2", 
"QnSinV3", "QnSize", "QnWt", "QnWtLsCL", "ClaustPer", "QnSurvCL", 
"ColWtCL", "ColWtCL_6", "ColGrowthCL_6", "QnSurvCL_6", "IR", 
"SH", "HL", "MLH"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
27L, 28L, 29L, 31L, 34L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L), class = "data.frame")
```

My guess (which doesn't work):

```
test<-subset(data, data$ColWtCL_6=='NA')
test
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can do it also without `subset()`. To select NA values you should use function `is.na()`.

```
data[is.na(data$ColWtCL_6),]
```

Or with `subset()`

```
subset(data,is.na(ColWtCL_6))
```

Comment: @Didzis, thanks for a simple solution. How to approach this problem in case of multiple conditions? Where `Column1` has value, but `Column2 ` and `Column3 ` is equal to `NA`

Answer (score 21):

A *tidyverse* approach (package `dplyr`):

```
test <- 
  data %>% 
  filter(is.na(ColWtCL_6))
```

If you want to filter based on NAs in multiple columns, please consider using function `filter_at()` in combinations with a valid function to select the columns to apply the filtering condition and the filtering condition itself.

Example 1: select rows of `data` with NA in **all** columns starting with `Col`:

```
test <-
  data %>%
  filter_at(vars(starts_with("Col")), all_vars(is.na(.)))
```

Example 2: select rows of `data` with NA in **one of** the columns starting with `Col`:

```
test <-
  data %>%
  filter_at(vars(starts_with("Col")), any_vars(is.na(.)))
```

This link from tidyverse documentation is very inspiring: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter_all.html

Answer (score 6):

Here's another solution to find `ǸA`'s across all columns in a dataframe using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

# get column names
colnms <- colnames(df)

# filter
df %>%
  filter_at(vars(all_of(colnms)), any_vars(is.na(.)))
```